# Instagram keeps sending me text messages

Tags: notifications, instagram

I turned off all my push notifications, and I still keep getting text from Instagram, e.g. when someone liked my photos or left a message. But I also keep receiving txt messages from Instagram telling me about things like whats new on instagram, or for me to check out a someone i have no interest is doing.

I still have my Instagram and like the service just want Instagram to stop txting my in the middle of the night with things I don't want to be informed with.

How can I stop them from texting me all night long?

Comment: What kind of messages are you getting? Is it when somebody likes your photo?

Comment: This looks suspiciously similar to http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48803/instagram-notifications

Comment: I had been receiving Txt messages when someone liked my photos or left a message. But I also keep receiving txt messages from Instagram telling me about things like whats new on instagram, or for me to check out a someone i have no interest is doing. I still have my Instagram and like the service just want Instagram to stop txting my in the middle of the night with things I don't want to be informed with.

Comment: Is it really SMS ? Or is it notifications ? Notifications can often be disabled in the application settings. If it is text message, then it can be disabled in your Instagram account settings (but I have never heard of such an option for Instagram).

Comment: You should have [edited](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/48876/edit) that into your question, which would automatically have nominated it to be re-opened. As the reason for putting it on hold no longer stands, chances are good it will be opened again. Just as a hint for a possible "next time" -- I just did that for you on this question.

Comment: If you're following Instagram on Twitter, either unfollow them, or "turn off" text notifications on Twitter

Comment: I had this same issue. Turning off all notifications in Instagram didn't help - this is actually a twitter notification from following instagram on twitter.

Answer (score 2):

Open Instagram... Then go to "Edit Your Profile" and then delete your mobile number from your profile... Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

Just text "stop"  to the number sending you those annoying  messages.  worked for me!

Comment: Comment from [user60710](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/60710/user60710) (who lacks the rep to do so): *texting "stop" was the answer. This was a twitter notification from following instagram. Shutting off notifications in twitter didn't work but replying stop did the job! Thank you! Even my teenage kids couldn't help!*